# How to debug these internal server errors?

Tags: php, apache2

I am not a server admin but do have some experience with Linux servers but mostly in Django and Nginx. Someone at our company has left suddenly for personal reasons and we have a site running on PHP with two pages that are showing internal server error messages that I need to fix.

I have done a fair bit of searching here and on Google and tried a few things already but still stuck, these are the urls to the pages (domain removed):

http://dev.mydomain.com/user/login/index.php

http://dev.mydomain.com/ew-admin/submit.php

I first did a grep search for the index.php url in the Apache error logs and found this:

```
[Fri Mar 10 06:15:51.083887 2017] [core:error] [pid 24087]    [client 121.97.206.98:54740] AH00124: Request exceeded the    limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.     Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary.     Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer:        http://dev.mydomain.com/user/login/index.php
```

and then after Googling those errors I found this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071324/request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects

this is my .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and I tried adding the line that was suggested in the SO thread to the .htaccess file but that didnt seem to change anything.

So next I checked the file and folder permissions for where those files are stored, they weren't set to 755 so I changed them to that, still getting internal server error though.

I should all that the public_html/ directory has these two directories in them:

dev/
old_mydomain/dev

the dev/ directory is empty and old_mydomain/dev directory seems to have the files for these two urls that are showing errors so I tried moving all the files from old_mydomain/dev to the empty dev/ directory seeing as the url has the 'dev.' subdomain but that didnt work either so I moved the files back.

I found an error_log within the old_mydomain/dev directory too with the following in but this seems to have stopped logging errors in the summer of last year and I know that these two urls were working just a few months back:

```
[21-Jul-2016 11:45:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to toolbarqueries.google.com:80 (Network is unreachable) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/pagerank.php on line 85
[29-Jul-2016 06:03:09 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
[30-Jul-2016 13:22:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
[31-Jul-2016 10:38:20 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
[07-Aug-2016 13:32:34 UTC] PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to toolbarqueries.google.com:80 (Network is unreachable) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/pagerank.php on line 85
[08-Aug-2016 20:37:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
[09-Aug-2016 23:58:17 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) in /home/eatonweb/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
[11-Aug-2016 00:04:53 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
[16-Aug-2016 22:27:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
[17-Aug-2016 23:57:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in /home/mydomain/public_html/dev/hide/init.php on line 14
```

Thats all I can think of for debugging and Im stumped right now, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to find out which entity exactly is sending those redirects, and then fix the code. It is most likely the PHP script.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I managed to figure this out and going to answer it myself now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So found the problem with some assistance, it seems there was no .htaccess file in dev.mydomain.com so the .htaccess in root was being used which was configured differently and this caused the server errors.